# java listview change Content

Tags: java, android

```
private String[] listView2 = {"aa","bb","cc","dd","ee"};

listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listView2);
listView1.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Change listView2[1] to "zzz".

Following code isn't work.

```
listView2[1] = "zzz";
```

Comment: did you call `listAdapter.notifydatasetchanged()` after the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can update adapter like this:**

```
  adapter.insert("zz", 1);
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Two problems with this answer 1) Question was about changing one item, not adding 2) using the adapter methods doesn't (by default) require calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 1):

you also need to call

```
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Or use one of the listAdpater methods for changing the data:

```
add(T), insert(T, int), remove(T), clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.^_^

```
public void newListView(){
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listView2);
    listView1.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

listView2[0] = "zz";
newListView();
```